# Salesforce will be helping "Registered" partners with leads

Tags: partner-communities, partner-portal

We are looking for Salesforce leads and planning to go for Salesforce partnership
We can start with Registered partnership. We wanted to check whether Salesforce will be helping "Registered" partners with leads.
Will we be getting Partner Account Manager? What support we will be getting from manager?

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't; Partner Account Manager is a Platinum [benefit](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/consultants/Consulting_Partner_Benefits).